# Symfony, Command and routes

Tags: php, symfony, routes, command, contextmenu

Maybe a stupid one but it might help me to save lots of code rewriting.
I have a Symfony 4.1 app that generates PDF files by calling routes inside a controller.
Unfortunately the PDF creation time has grown exponentially and now I got the 504 timeout...so I want to do a compromise and don't feed the PDF in real time as a downloadable file inside the browser but use a cronjob + command file that will generate the PDFs, then notify the user with a mail that has a downloadable link inside.
Can I run/execute a route inside a Command? (like "mysite.com/print_person/1234") I don't know, by using Router/Context stuff (like a sandbox maybe)?

Thanks

Already tried to run the controller->print_person() from the Command, of course it works but I already have the generated routes and it would be brilliant to run it directly from the Command

Comment: you should use the messenger component. here is a free tutorial to help get you started: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/messenger. Move all your pdf generation code into a MessageHandler and then spin a new message to send the email. You'll need to store the pdf in an accessible place also.

Comment: There is no direct way to execute a route from a command.  With some effort you could probably instantiate the controller and call the action directly though you would have to deal with the response object.  Ideally the PDF code would already be in it's own service that the command could call directly.  But I am guessing it is not and you are trying to avoid moving it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The messenger component seems the way to go, thx